# I am trying to use boostrap to generate a parrallel navbar effect in a vertical navbar utlizing the grid system

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to get the links in my vertical nav bar to align properly ,and turn my current navigation bar into two columns of right links and left links.[Here is a link to a  jsfiddle with the navigation bar I am currently using.](http://jsfiddle.net/2ozehw1d/1/) Below I will include the relevant code that is included in the jsfiddle.

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
  <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
    <li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>

</ul>
</form>
  </li>
</ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
   .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }

  .navbar
  {
  max-width:300px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
   }    

  .navbar-nav,
  .navbar-nav > li,
  .navbar-left,
  .navbar-right,
  .navbar-header
  {float:none !important;}

  .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {left:0;right:auto;}
  .navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
   }
   }
```

I am trying to have two vertical rows one for the right links and one for the left links. Thank you for your time in advance.

Sincerely,
fredk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.  One, you can stagger your links (not recommended) like so:

```
<li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
<li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
<li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
<li><a class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"href="#">RightLink</a></li>
```

This is a problem because one column might have more links than the other.

The solution, is to get rid of the formatting in the  anchor tags, and wrap the unordered list tag with a div defining the column there.  Like so:

```
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li><a class=""href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
      <li><a class=""href="#">LeftLink</a></li>
...</ul></div>
```

I have a working example in this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ozehw1d/2/